# Including point heat sources in a 2D transient PDE heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I want to be sure that I included the point heat sources correctly in my PDE.
The result should be:
[image]

I wrote:

```
q0 = 1;
Subscript[Q, 0] = 
  q0*(DiracDelta[x - x1]*DiracDelta[y - y1] + 
     DiracDelta[x - x1]*DiracDelta[y - y2]*DiracDelta[x - x2]*
      DiracDelta[y - y1] + DiracDelta[x - x2]*DiracDelta[y - y2]);
heqn1 = Subscript[k, 
    CLS]*(D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], x, x] + 
      D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], y, y]) + Subscript[Q, 0] == 
  Subscript[\[Rho], CLS]*Subscript[Cp, CLS]*
   D[Subscript[T, D][x, y, t], t]
```

I haven't considered the time-dependency for the heat source just yet to simplify the notation.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There is an example of this in the documentation. Have a look at the [Heat Transfer Monograph](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html). There is a section on [Sources](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#945943234) and a subsection on [Point Sources](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#862770857).

The following is copied from there. For more information read the sections mentioned:

```
Subscript[\[Rho], air] = ThermodynamicData["Air", "Density"];
Subscript[Cp, air] = 
  ThermodynamicData["Air", "IsobaricHeatCapacity"];
Subscript[k, air] = ThermodynamicData["Air", "ThermalConductivity"];
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.2}];
tend = 600;
vars = {T[t, x, y], t, {x, y}};
pars = <|"ThermalConductivity" -> Subscript[k, air], 
   "MassDensity" -> Subscript[\[Rho], air], 
   "SpecificHeatCapacity" -> Subscript[Cp, air]|>;
RegularizedDeltaPoint[\[Gamma]_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ 
     Thread[1/(4 \[Gamma]) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 \[Gamma]) (X - Xs)])], 
    And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 \[Gamma]]}, {0, True}}]
xs = 0.1;
ys = 0.1;
reg = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.2}];
mesh = NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[reg, "IncludePoints" -> {{xs, ys}}];
Subscript[h, mesh] = Sqrt[Min[mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]];
Subscript[\[Gamma], reg] = Subscript[h, mesh]/2;

\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(Qp\), \(~\)]\) = 10;
pars["HeatSource"] = 
 RegularizedDeltaPoint[Subscript[\[Gamma], reg], {x, y}, {xs, ys}]*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(Qp\), \(~\)]\)
pde = {HeatTransferPDEComponent[vars, pars] == 0, T[0, x, y] == 0};
Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {t, 0, tend}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
pRange = MinMax[Tfun["ValuesOnGrid"]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", pRange}, Sequence[
   50, LegendLabel -> Style["[\[Degree]C]", 
Opacity[0.6]]]];
options = {PlotRange -> pRange, Sequence[
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", pRange}], 
    ContourStyle -> None, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["Transient Temperature Field: T(t,x,y)", 18], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Contours -> 75, PlotPoints -> 41, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]};
boundaryHighlight = Graphics[{{
Directive[Purple, Thick], 
Point[{xs, ys}]}, 
Text[
Style["Point Heat Source \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Q\), \(p\)]\)", 14, 
      Black], {0.11, 0.125}]}];
nframes = 30;
frames = Table[
   Show[Legended[
     ContourPlot[Tfun[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
      Evaluate[options]], legendBar], boundaryHighlight], {t, 0, tend,
     tend/nframes}];
frames = Rasterize[#1, "Image", ImageResolution -> 80] & /@ frames;
ListAnimate[frames, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried changing the domain with mine and I've put the location for my point heat source, but I'm not able to add more than one. Most importantly, I don't understand what this line means: "RegularizedDeltaPoint[\[Gamma]_, X_List, Xs_List] := 
 Piecewise[{{Times @@ Thread[1/(4 \[Gamma]) (1 + Cos[\[Pi]/(2 \[Gamma]) (X - Xs)])], 
    And @@ Thread[RealAbs[X - Xs] <= 2 \[Gamma]]}, {0, True}}]".